# Direct data input from Django for a D3 graph

Tags: javascript, django, json, d3.js

It seems all the D3 example graphs take an external .csv or .tsv file as input data. Is there any way to modify the code to take data from a variable in Django. Suppose {{ data }} is in JSON format, how do you implement this in a graph such as http://bl.ocks.org/3885304 or http://bl.ocks.org/3887051 ? I'm trying to avoid always writing a .csv file.

Comment: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json

Comment: If I'm using d3.json, what is the URL and callback?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted to serve it as json using http. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always make a view which will serve dynamic csv file which will be consumed by D3. This way will also allow users to download the data in case they need the raw data instead of a graph.

```
def foo(request, ...):
    model = get_object_or_404(Foo, ...)
    data = model.get_data() # should return csv formatted string
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='text/csv')
```

Comment: If you are doing this a lot consider an api like tastypie https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie

Comment: Also, I agree with Miki725 re csv.  After serving both csv and json to d3 from django, I now stick with csv as there are some good tools like d3.nest and crossfilter for refining selections and csv is smaller to transfer than json.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of loading data asynchronously (ajax-style), you can use correctly formatted JSON in a string passed to your template tag variable and `|safe`d.

Check out the working example http://bl.ocks.org/4040034 which is based on http://bl.ocks.org/3885304

You should also check out the related questions on SO, there are tons on the subject.

Comment: That graph is what I'm looking for. My {{ data }} is in exactly the format of their var data, which is JSON. Can I simply replace their data with var data = {{ data }}? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The key is the `|safe` to bypass the default django escaping of strings.