# Django and d3.js: CSV data

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js

I'm trying to get django to serve CSV data from a Model to generate a graph using d3.js. This example works when I have the same CSV data sitting on the server and I pass scatter a path to the CSV file.

I'm following the solution posted here [Direct data input from Django for a D3 graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293174/direct-data-input-from-django-for-a-d3-graph) to serve the CSV data.

I am getting an error in the scatter function claiming that the data passed is null.

### views.py

```
def serve_data(request):
    model = get_object_or_404(FileData, pk = 1)
    data = model.get_data()
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type = "text/csv")
```

### template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('/site/serve_data/', function(data) 
    {
        $('.result').html(data);
        scatter(data); // Here's the call to the javascript function
    });
</script>
```

### javascript

```
function scatter(csvData)
{
    // ERROR HERE: csvData is null
    d3.csv(csvData, function(data)
    {
        data.forEach(function(d) 
        {
        // work with data
        });
    });
});
```

Am I on the right track?

#### EDIT

The `serve_data` function does return CSV data when I call the URL from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply misusing `d3.csv`, it expects a URL. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-csv

Comment: Bingo. parseRows was what I was looking for. RTFM!