# Django - d3.js communication without explicit request?

Tags: json, django, d3.js

I'm struggling with a django queryset to be passed to d3.js for plotting.
What I'm trying to do:
 - I have a form which allow the user to make specific queries in my database (this is working really fine).
 - The result of that search are all ordered by date (more below) but may be a lot (between 0 to 20 000). So I don't want to display them as a list but make a bar chart.

The problem: I don't know what would be the best method to transfer the results to d3js, since I'm returning more to my view than just what I want to plot.

my views.py:

```
    class QBinnedImages(View):
        template_name = 'data/query_simple.html'
        form_class = QueryImages

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            ### working fine

        def form_valid(self, form):
            ### Do some stuff to get the query results
            context = {"title":"Query Results", "form":form, \
                       "ndata":len(alldates), "data":JsonResponse(alldates)}
            return render(self.request, 'data/query_results.html', context)
     class QueryResults(View):
         template_name='data/query_results.html'
```

The alldates is a dictionary of the form:

```
    {"N": ["20150926T230027", "20150926T230547", "20150926T231106", \
           "20150926T233741", "20150926T234301", "20150926T234820", \
           "20150926T235339", "20150926T235858", "20150927T000936",]}
```

for the moment my template data/query_results.html look like this:

```
    {% entends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
      <div id="blablabla">
        <h1> {{ title }} </h1>

        <p> You queried with the following constrains : </p>
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <p> We found {{ ndata }} satisfying your query </p>
      </div>
      <div id="plots">
          <svg class="bresults"> </svg>
      </div>
     <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <script>
      // definition of the axis and other small stuff
      d3.json( "{{ data }}", function(error, data) {
          if (error) return console.warn(error);
          x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
          });
      </script>
      {% endblock content %}
```

And the bug is at d3.json off course. I do understand that d3.json actually send a requests for a json stream ... but I'm stuck there.

I hope there is enough information here to help me out

Thaaaaanks!!!

Comment: To pass a django's variable to JS I whink you just need: `var list = {{ data }};` or `var list = '{{ data }}';`

Comment: hmmm... Agreed I no longer have the error ... however now all the " are skewed:    {u&#39;N&#39;: [&#39;20150926T230027&#39;, &#39;20150926T230547&#39;, &#39;20150926T231106&#39;, &#39;20150926T233741&#39;, &#39;20150926T234301&#39;, &#39;20150926T234820&#39;, &#39;20150926T235339&#39;,

Comment: Using `var list = {{ data }};` didn't work?

Comment: Try using [`escapejs` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) -> `{{ data|escapejs }}`

Comment: Indeed it's much better now!!! I may be able from there to work my way towards the plot... slowly ... very slowly ...                                                     I wonder, could this way of sending the information to d3.js get slow if the amount of results I'm passing get largish (20000)?

Comment: Did you use `var list = {{ data }};` or `var list = '{{ data }}';`?

Comment: I used the var list = " {{ data |escapejs }}";   
And I also no longer use JsonResponse in the context definition:
Hence in the views.py:
    `context = {..., "data":alldates}`

Comment: Good for you, I will provide this as an answer for other poeple with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to make the plot. 
Actually passing the data is awfully simple, but ... as long as you don't know exactly how, impossible to guess.
in short: in the template I just wrote

```
    var data = {{ data | safe }};
```

But other changes had to be made in the views! No JSON needed, as long as the output is roughly a list of dictionary.

in views.py:

```
    alldates = [{'camera':'N', 'days':t[0].isoformat(), \
                 'counts':c['total_counts']} \
                  for t, c in zip(times, counts_per_day)]
    context = {"title":"Query Results", "form":form, \
                   "ndata":len(alldates), "data":alldates}
    return render(self.request, 'data/query_results.html', context)
```

then in the template:

```
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").parse;
    var data = {{ data | safe}};
    data.forEach(function(d) {return d.days=parseDate(d.days);});
```

I was greatly helped by the answer of Martin [Direct data input from Django for a D3 graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293174/direct-data-input-from-django-for-a-d3-graph?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

To pass a Django's variable to a JS variable you need:

```
var js_variable = "{{ django_variable }};"
```

In your case:

```
<script>
  // definition of the axis and other small stuff
  var data = "{{ data|escapejs }}";  // transfer from django to js
  d3.json( data, function(error, data) {
      if (error) return console.warn(error);
      x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Ahhh, that's what you meant!!! It's not exactly how I solved it with your help. Here is the change/code I made. It is possible that your version also works, though I have some doubt (the d3.json is ... )  


`<script>  
  var data = "{{ data |escapejs }}";
  alert(data);  // for me to see what comes out
 </script>`

(Note the semi-colon is outside the " " )

Comment: I haven't validated yet the answer, for 2 reasons:
 1. I'd rather see the typos corrected
 2. I'm still not sure this is the way to proceed, since I've been unable so far to make use of the data variable in js.